# ngrx-store-logger as metaReducer is incompatible

Tags: angular, typescript, logging, ngrx

I use ngrx in my Angular 12 project and wanted to implement the [ngrx-store-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrx-store-logger) to log my actions and store.
Here's part of my app.module.ts

```
import { storeLogger } from 'ngrx-store-logger';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

export function logger(reducer: ActionReducer<AppState>): any {
  // default, no options
  return storeLogger()(reducer);
}

export const metaReducers = !environment.production? [logger] : [];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ]
  imports: [... StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }), ... ]

...
}
```

VSC throws this error:

```
  Types of parameters 'reducer' and 'reducer' are incompatible.
    Type '{ [x: string]: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'AppState': students, coachests(2322)
```

while my build executes without errors, there's just not any logging when executing any actions at all.

Comment: You didn't close the `logger` function or it's just a typo in the example?

Comment: that's a typo - sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I used the wrong reducer in my StoreModule. That fixed it!